# EF migration constraint already exists

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

I try to run an Entity Framework migration:

```
    public override void Up()
    {
        AlterColumn("dbo.ThubOutputEmails", "AttachmentName", c => c.String(nullable: true, maxLength: 256));
        SqlExecute("ALTER TABLE dbo.ThubOutputEmails ADD CONSTRAINT DF_ThubOutputEmail_Created default getdate() for Created");
    }
```

which is translated to the following script in `update-database` command:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ThubOutputEmails] ALTER COLUMN [AttachmentName] [nvarchar](256) NULL
EXECUTE('
ALTER TABLE dbo.ThubOutputEmails ADD CONSTRAINT DF_ThubOutputEmail_Created default getdate() for Created
')
```

It fails with message:

```
Column already has a DEFAULT bound to it
```

The problem is there isn't a DB constraint on the column, but the migration reports there is such a constraint already. When I copy and paste the SQL and run it in SQL Server Management Studio, it runs OK and the constraint is created.

Comment: I've seen issues related to default constraints and other column changes. There are cases where running the commands step by step in SSMS work, but because migrations run in a batch they do different things. Try splitting the column changes into 2 migrations and see if that works. Bug: https://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/2144

Comment: Thanks for the link. It was probably my mistake, the EF was setup so that it created a second database. I modified the script to create the constraint only if it does not exist.